# Mixin for data-overlay selector

Tags: css, sass

Is there a way to convert the following CSS rules to a Mixin or make it a bit more SCSS?

```
[data-overlay]:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background: #000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}

[data-overlay="0"]:before {
    opacity: 0;
}

[data-overlay="1"]:before {
    opacity: 0.1;
}

[data-overlay="2"]:before {
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sassmeister [demo](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/4c623d64f83a22a918f1e63dcc88825b).
Sass [`for`](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/if-for-each-while#for) loop.

```
@mixin overlays($count: 0) {
  [data-overlay]:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background: #000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  }

  @for $i from 0 through $count {
    [data-overlay="#{$i}"]:before {
      opacity: $i / 10;
    }
  }
}

@include overlays(4);
```

Comment: That's absolutely awesome it works perfectly. Thank you!!

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the solution. I was trying to port a mixin from .less and it helped me a lot!